# Number of solutions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, multinomial

I am stuck on a problem,

```
  x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 +x5 + x6 < M
```

where xi's are positive integers and M can be any value  from [1,6000000].
How many `unordered solutions with distinct xi's` exists.
I want to know  whether this can be done by dynamic programming( with it running fast with the given constraints and within memory limits) , or I have to come up with a combinotorics formula.
I have to report the `answer modulo 1000000007`
PS: I don't want the solution

Comment: what language, tools do you have ? python C ?

Comment: unordered solutions doesnot matter as (a+b)==(b+a)

Comment: If this is for a math problem you should better try to find the mathematical soltution anyway :)

Comment: yes unordered means (a,b,c,d,e,f)=(b,c,a,e,d,f)

Comment: this is not from some maths class its a programming question

Comment: For the memory limit, you need exactly 1 counter of solution, and 7 variables. So no problem (you just have to count the solutions). the problem is more the time. If youhave a cluster then you might use more memory OR, if you have multicore or CUDA available this can be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the complete solution, so I won't give it to you; I'll just try to point you in the right direction.

First of all, you need to decompose the problem in simpler ones. In your case, this do the trick:

```
|(x_1,...x6) : sum(x_i) < M | = sum( |(x_1,...,x6) : sum(x_i) = N|)
```

for `N=6,...,M-1` . Now, you only need different solutions, so you can assume that:

```
x_1 <= x_2 <= ... <= x_6
```

Now, counting the number of ways you can get `k` elements to sum up to `N` isn't that hard ( try first with 2 elements, than 3, and try to get the general forumla and, if you have some time on your hands, prove it by induction ), and once you have that you are basically done.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : as it should be clear by now, I think that the  combinotorics approach is way better than the brute force one

Comment: thnx will try to do so  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can go brute force, just create a vector (or other dynamic container ) to push solution while you go. This will not be a memory problem.
but this will be long to process.
Another idea is to create a fstream, and flush regularly (every 10000 solution);

Comment: Every problem can be solved by brute force, provide you have ample of time to wait for an answer